# Returning response data from a 'for loop' - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Reasonably new to Angular. I have a service which purpose is to get information from a JSON file, iterate through each object, so I can access the data from the controller. I can access the JSON data from the `$http` request, but not the JSON data from the for loop within the service.

Is this is the best way to loop through items in AngularJS, if so, how do I access and display this information from the controller?

```
app.factory('fxRate', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

var factory = {};

factory.getFx = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('../json/mcfx.json')
        .then(
            function(response){

                var d, i;

                var rateData = response.data.fxrate;

                for (var i in rateData) {
                    var fx = rateData[i].usdToEur;
                    var fxDate = rateData[i].date;
                }
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            }, 
            function(errResponse){
                deferred.reject(errResponse.data);
            }
        )

    return deferred.promise;

}

return factory;

}]);
```

---

```
app.controller('dashboard', ['$scope', 'fxRate', function($scope, fxRate){ 

$scope.dailyFx = function() {
    fxRate.getFx().then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
}

$scope.dailyFx();

}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple., return promise from `factory\service` and resolve in `controller`.
Like below:

**Factory**

```
app.factory('fxRate', ['$http', function($http){
var factory = {};
factory.getFx = function() {
    return $http.get('../json/mcfx.json');
}

return factory;
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('dashboard', ['$scope', 'fxRate', function($scope, fxRate){ 
$scope.dailyFx = function() {
    fxRate.getFx().then(function(resonse) {
        console.log(resonse.data)
        //handle resonse\data, or assign to some $scope property.
        var rateData = response.data.fxrate;
        for (var i in rateData) {
           var fx = rateData[i].usdToEur;
           var fxDate = rateData[i].date;
         }
    });
}

$scope.dailyFx();
}])
```

To show this data on `view\html`, you need to assign this to some `$scope` property, like `$scope.fxRateData = response.data.fxrate`, and then in html render it the way you want.

For example only :

```
<div ng-repeat="fxrate in fxRateData track by $index">
  <span>{{fxrate.usdToEur}}</span>
  <span>{{fxrate.date}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is true, though if I wanted to keep functions separate from the controller....... how would I go about that?

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott : your function `$scope.dailyFx()` is quite separate and further you can extracta nother method from response section, if you do some manipulation with `response.data`., like some `handleResponse(response.data)`